# Update ManyToManyField() with a queryset, is it possible with django ORM?

Tags: django, performance, django-models

**Hello Awesome People!**

I will try to make my question simple as much I can.

So is it possible to avoid the `for loop` in the following example?

```
for instance in Model.objects.filter(done=True):
    instance.field_name.add(*queryset)
```

I want to update a `ManyToManyField` inside a queryset. Basically I'm just asking if I can do something like:

```
Model.objects.filter(done=True).update(field_name__add=*something)
```

Comment: As far as I know I don't think it's possible, you will need to use `for` loop

Comment: Maybe someone has achieved that before! this may be useful for other people, it's kind of tricky to loop through queryset just to update a specific ManyToManyField